# MySQL Moving more than 1 row to another table, all in 1 statement?

Tags: mysql

So I need to insert all rows outputted from this statement into separate table:

```
    SELECT * FROM children WHERE quoteid = '$quoteid'
```

This only inserts one of the rows:

```
    INSERT INTO beneficiaries (quoteid, uid, name, percent) VALUES('$quoteid', '$uid', '$nm', '10')
```

Anyone know a way to move more than one row or do I have to send them all separately?

UPDATE:

Should've mentioned this before, but no, 'children' doesn't have same column names, and changing them isn't an option. Sorry!

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM beneficiaries WHERE quoteid = '$quoteid'");
$getchildrenrid2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0)
{
    $getchildren = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM children WHERE quoteid = '$quoteid'");
    $getchildrenrid = mysql_fetch_assoc($getchildren);

        $nm = $getchildrenrid['first_name'] . " " . $getchildrenrid['surname'];
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO beneficiaries (quoteid, uid, name, percent) VALUES('$quoteid', '$uid', '$nm', '10')");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM beneficiaries WHERE quoteid = '$quoteid'");
        $getlastchild = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

            header("Location: ".$conf['location']."/distribution.php?edit=".$getlastchild['id']);
}
```

'children' columns:

```
- id
- **quoteid**
- **uid**
- *first_name*
- middle_names
- *surname*
- dob
- guardian_first_name
- guardian_middlenames
- guardian_nickname
- guardian_surname
- guardian_housenum
- guardian_city
- guardian_street
- guardian_postcode
```

'beneficiaries' columns

```
- id
- **quoteid**
- **uid**
- *name*
- **percent**
```

What needs copying over:

- quoteid INTO quoteid
- uid INTO uid
- first_name + last_name INTO name
- and set percent as '10'

Also, this should be done only after this: SELECT * FROM children WHERE quoteid = '$quoteid' is done.

$quoteid returns current quote's unique quoteid.

Comment: Why not just `INSERT INTO beneficiaries (quoteid, uid, name, percent) SELECT *, 10 FROM CHILDREN WHERE quoteid = '$quoteid'`?

Comment: No one is telling you to change column names in the children table, just specify the appropriate columns when doing `INSERT SELECT`

Comment: Yeah I'm new to programming, sorry I'll update again so its easier for you to understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you provide the table structure for each table, we can probably do a `JOIN` to create a single `INSERT` statement. You also need to stop using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: see update, table names and what needs to go where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO beneficiaries (quoteid, uid, name, percent) select
quoteid, uid, name, percent from children WHERE quoteid = '$quoteid';
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `children` has the same column names...

```
INSERT INTO beneficiaries (quoteid, uid, name, percent)
SELECT quoteid, uid, name, percent FROM children WHERE quoteid = '$quoteid'
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO beneficiaries (quoteid, uid, name, percent) SELECT quoteid, uid, name, percent FROM children WHERE quoteid = '$quoteid'`;

Adjust column names as needed.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO beneficiaries (quoteid, uid, name, percent) SELECT (quoteid, uid, name, percent) FROM children WHERE quoteid = '$quoteid'`

That query will do as you asked, assuming that the columns are compatible, of course.

source: [MySQL Docs: INSERT ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)